# image not showing in the desired place with plugin metabox

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I have used a plugin (Meta box 4.8.3) to create custom meta box and get values in custom post. If custom meta box field is text then the function returns the value. If it is image then it do not show the images.

**Register  custom meta-box **

```
    add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'your_prefix_meta_boxes' );
    function your_prefix_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
    'title'      => __( 'Image Gallery', 'textdomain' ),
    'post_types' => 'events',
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'name' => __( 'Image Upload', 'your-prefix' ),
            'id'   => $prefix . 'test_image',
            'type' => 'image_advanced',
        ),

    ),
);
return $meta_boxes;
```

}

**To get the images the code is this**

```
   function getgallery(){
    //global $post;

            $image =  wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'test_image',1));
            if ( !empty( $image ) ) {
            foreach ( $image as $images ) {
             ?>
                <div class="eventsinfo-detail">
                    <div class="row events-info">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="events-detail">
                              <div class="event-image">
                              <a href="#"><?php echo $image; ?></a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                </div>
                 <?php
                }
            }   
}
```

How can i display the images which i uploaded through the dashboard.

The question is updated

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code and confirm whether the code works or not?:

**Display Single Image**

```
$attachment_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'test_image', true);
echo wp_get_attachment_image(attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
```

**Display Multiple Image**

```
$attachment_ids = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'test_image');
foreach($attachment_ids AS $attachment_id){
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
}
```

**Your Code** Try this

```
 function getgallery(){
        $images =  wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'test_image'));
        if ( count( $images ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $images AS $image ) {
         ?>
            <div class="eventsinfo-detail">
                <div class="row events-info">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <div class="events-detail">
                          <div class="event-image">
                          <a href="#"><?php echo $image; ?></a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            </div>
             <?php
            }
        }
```

Comment: @waqasjr.developer: I have cross-checked my code at my end and its working perfectly fine with my code of multiple images. Can you please post your updated code so that i can help you out?

Comment: $image =  wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'test_image',1));
    
    foreach ( $image as $images ) {
        ?>
                 <div class="eventsinfo-detail">
                     
       
                                  <a href="#"><?php echo $image; ?></a>
                                  </div>
                             
                           </div>
                      </div>                                                                                              
                 </div>
                     <?php
     }
    } 
 }

Comment: is there any difference between them

Comment: @waqasjr.developer: Try your code which i have modified. To display multiple images, don't use last parameter or use FALSE instead of TRUE in last parameter of get_post_meta and remove $prefix, no need of $prefix

Comment: @waqasjr.developer: Try updated Answer as per your updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107308/discussion-between-waqas-jr-developer-and-mehul-gohil).

Answer (score 1):

```
$attachment_args = array( 
'post_type' => 'attachment', 
'post_status' => 'inherit', 
'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 
); 

$images = new WP_Query($attachment_args); 

if ($images->have_posts()) : 

while ($images->have_posts()) : $images->the_post(); 

$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_the_ID(),'test_image'); // where get_the_ID() is id of attachment 
echo '<img src="'. esc_url( $img[0]) .'" />'; 

endwhile; 


endif; 

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Try the updated code now...

Comment: it is showing some static three images.not increasing nor decreasing

Comment: add post_count in args

Comment: $attachment_args = array( 
'post_type' => 'attachment', 
'post_status' => 'inherit', 
'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 
'post_count' => -1
);